# Remove scrollbar jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am developing a plugin on wordpress (currently using Twenty Thirteen theme) that when you click a `div` a modal will show. Whenever the modal is showing I want to remove the scrollbar on body.

I used the code below but it seems it doesn't work:

```
jQuery("#page").css("overflow", "hidden");
jQuery('body').css('overflow','hidden');
```

I can see `style="overflow: hidden;"` on firebug is being added but the scrollbar is still showing.

I also tried using `!IMPORTANT` like `jQuery('body').css('overflow','hidden!IMPORTANT');` but still not working

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: also set the window height on body

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('body').css({
'overflow': 'hidden'
'height'  : $( window ).height()
});
```

Comment: This is only disable the scrollbar.. But I can still see the scrollbar

Comment: do you set margin:0 and padding: 0, that is default appear on body

Answer (score 0):

See my fiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/d89ascrz/)

Because your body doesn't have a set height, it isn't overflowing so overflow doesn't do anything by itself. When the dialogue is visible, add a `height` to your body.

```
body.dialog-visible {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is only disable the scrollbar.. But I can still see the scrollbar on my browser

Answer (score 0):

use this css fro removing the scrollbar

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

be sure to use in proper tag otherwise it will hide all scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style:

```
<style>
BODY #s4-workspace 
{
OVERFLOW-X: hidden !important;OVERFLOW-Y: hidden !important;
}
</style>
```

This removes both scroll bars.